# How do I link an image field to an pdf file

Tags: views

I have a challenge in linking my image to a pdf file. I have a content type with 2 fields, image field which will contain the cover picture and an attachment field which is file of type pdf.

In my view am trying to link an image to attachment so that when a user clicks on the image it open a pdf file.

In some instances where am just using description to link to a pdf file, this what I have put in my Global PHP(Description) output code in my view. 
nid, 'filename.pdf');
?>
As soon as click on the description my pdf opens. works fine

But I need to do the same thing with my image, to just click on image then should open my pdf file. Any idea???

Comment: may be this will help http://serpastian.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-link-image-to-pdf-file-in-drupal.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7 you can use VIEWS **Rewrite results** to link an IMAGE to a PDF file.

Steps:

- In PDF field, exclude it and change the **format** to "**URL of file**"

  [image]
- Go to your **VIEW** -> **Image field** and under **Link image to** select **NOTHING**
- And then go to **Rewrite results** and check **Output this field as a
  link** and give the path of the PDF file.

  [image]

  [image]
- You can also use **TOKENS** by using **Replacement patterns** for PDF file  path name

  [image]

Comment: Your welcome.. enjoy :)

Comment: Be sure you have your PDF field arranged first in the list followed by your imagefield, otherwise the image will not know what to link to.

Comment: I took me a bit to realize -- it is a way down in the dialoge in a collapsed "replacement pattern menue" --- that the possible replacement are directly suggested for the page in questions, as in the example above. So you can "copy and paste" In contrast to drupal 7, in drupal 8 the fields have the format {{ field_file_u_upload }} == Content: File u upload

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the [Image link to file](https://drupal.org/project/image_link_to_file) module, which I developed because I had the same problem. The module is very small and very simple to use. It is stable, even though it's an alpha release.

Hope this helps

—Alex

Answer (score -2):

You can go to your view>Click on the fild name(image) >After you select from list **Link image to** the option File.

And that's it.

Comment: it is exactly what am doing but its just opens the cover page instead of the whole pdf file.